# CIVIEVENT shopping cart status

Tags: civievent, documentation

I'm considering testing the shopping cart functionality in CiviCRM's CiviEvent module (installed here with Drupal 7) and was wondering if anything has changed in the [description page on the CiviCRM site](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviEvent+Cart+Checkout) that includes bug reports. I saw it was last updated in 2013 - thought I'd check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There have been no significant changes or modifications to the shopping cart functionality in CiviEvent. You might want to give it a shot and see if it does work for you and/or meets your needs.

I suspect that code needs some love and care and might require some developer skills to fix and improve. There is no maintainer for that part of the civievent code base

Answer (score 2):

I'm talking to Dave Greenberg about this later today actually so I'll let you know. But from my initial tests, it needs some work to get working smoothly.

Jon-man

Comment: Hi - would be great to hear an update if there is any.  FYI: I'm also wondering about using cart for donations and if that is something being considered.

Comment: hi Sonicthoughts, I'm not aware cart can be used for donations but it looks like cart is unsupported in CiviCRM 4.6.x. I am liaising with GiantRabbit, who contributed to the core originally to get the code working nicely.

Comment: Any update jon-man?

Comment: Event cart is not supported properly in latest versions of CiviCRM. I eventually spoke with Giant Rabbit who helped me with some customisation, but again, CiviCRM has moved on.

https://civicrm.org/blog/giantrabbit/case-study-civicrm-multiple-event-registration